# Convert List<ExpandoObject> to List<KeyValuePair>

Tags: c#, json, keyvaluepair, expandoobject

I'm currently working on a .NET Framework 4.7.2 application. From a web service response, I need to parse JSON data to a `List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, object>>>`. This datatype is important for the further program flow, I cannot change it.

The JSON data with dynamic properties looks like that:

```
{ "data" : [
   {"Id":1, Text:"Test1", coolProp: 213 },
   {"Id":2, Text:"Test2"},
   {"Id":3, Text:"Test3", otherProp: "cool" },
]}
```

I tried the following coding, but it didn't work:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, object>>>>(Convert.ToString(JObject.Parse(json)["data"]));
```

On the other hand i can convert the json to an ExpandoObject:

```
var expando = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExpandoObject>>(Convert.ToString(JObject.Parse(json)["data"]));
```

I'm thought about writing a private method to convert the 
ExpandoObject into my `List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, object>>>`.

```
private KeyValuePair<float, List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, object>>>> ConvertExpandoToKeyValue(float key, List<ExpandoObject> expando)
{
    var result = new KeyValuePair<float, List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, object>>>>();

    // I don't really know how to convert the expando object to the desired data structure
    // Moreover I need to put a float key in the structure: 52.2343

    return result;
}
```

The ExpandoObject looks like this:

[image]

The final result a `KeyValuePair<float, List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, object>>>>` should look like that:

[image]

Do you know how to convert the ExpandoObject to the desired data type and add a key at the beginning?

Or perhaps, do you know a better way to convert the JSON data to my desired data structure?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: is this necessary => `List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, object>>>` bcoz your json has dynamic properties or you welcome any other approach to handle dynamic json?

Comment: hi ershoaib, it would be good if i could get the json data into a List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, object>>>, because all other parts of the software rely on that specific structure...

Comment: could u plz add how your data will be look inside `List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, object>>>` so i get the idea to prepare answer for you

Comment: and also add your `ExpandoObject`

Comment: are the provided screen captures sufficient? :)

Comment: @ershoaib ExpandoObject is a built-in type. It's kind of a dynamic object.

Comment: @timhorton42, in your json `Id` will be key for keyvaluepair and remaining data goes to ` Dictionary<string, object>`?

Comment: yes, that's correct, thank you already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I wrote a solution, I just wanted to share with you. Perhaps there is a better way though:

```
private KeyValuePair<float, List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, object>>>> ConvertExpandoToKeyValue(float key, List<ExpandoObject> expando)
{
    var result = new KeyValuePair<float, List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, object>>>>
        (key, new List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, object>>>());

    for (int i = 0; i < expando.Count; i++)
    {
        var element = new Dictionary<string, object>(expando[i]);

        var propertyValues = new KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, object>>(i, element);

        result.Value.Add(propertyValues);
    }

    return result;
}
```